# Saving cart details into database

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I have a cart table which has a relation to a product table that i am using to save user's cart details to db. But i have a problem how can i save quantity of products?

I mean something like 2x of 298 (which is a id of a product)?

Comment: share details of your table and desired result clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

product_to_cart

```
+---------+------------+-----+
| cart_id | product_id | qty |
+---------+------------+-----+
| x       | x          | x   |

...
```

With a compound primary key comprising `cart_id` and `product_id` ?