# E-commerce cart saved with Doctrine2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to save cart content into database with Doctrine2. Currently, I'm stuck with proposal of entities. I have no idea how to save quantity of each item in order. I know it should be [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027068/saving-cart-details-into-database), but I don't know how to realize that.

```php
class Order
{
    …

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\EcommerceBundle\Entity\Client", inversedBy="orders")
     */ 
    private $client;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\EcommerceBundle\Entity\Item")
     */    
    private $items;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of direct using `Item` entity, you have to create new entity `OrderItem`:

```php
class OrderItem
{
    …

    private $qty;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\EcommerceBundle\Entity\Order")
     */ 
    private $order;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\EcommerceBundle\Entity\Item")
     */    
    private $item;
}
```

And in your `Order` entity use following mapping:

```php
class Order
{
    …

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Acme\EcommerceBundle\Entity\OrderItem")
     */    
    private $items;
}
```